# I'm having trouble with dictionaries in python

Tags: python

I'm writing code with `Python`.  I have defined a lot of dictionaries and a function. I use the dictionary in the function. The dictionary name is the parameter's in function .
I want to get user input which dictionary to use but I don't know how to do this. I tried to get the name of the dictionary with the name in the code line below but it didn't

```
name=input()
bank("name") 
error is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "............", line 47, in <module>
    banka("hesap")
  File "...................", line 18, in banka
    print("merhaba",hesap['ad'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Can we see your code so far?

Comment: I don't know how to share the long version here. I'm new here. I can send you if you tell me how to throw it personally

Comment: You are right. Posting dozens of lines of code wouldn't help. It is essential that you narrow it down to the part where the problem is located.

Answer (score 1):

It's this part of your code:

```
hesap['ad']
```

According to the error, `hasep` is a string, not a dictionary. So you can only put integers into the square brackets.

Comment: hesap=input()
banka([hesap])
I did this way but didnt work. thanks for help

Comment: dict1:{..}    dict2:{......}   
    def bank(dictionaty)
        ......,
        .......
        .......
  dict=input()
 banka(dict)

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe do someting like this

```
dictionary1 = {}
dictionary2 = {}
user_input = input("Enter 'dictionary1' for dictionary 1 or enter 'dictionary2' for dictionary 2")
if user_input ==  "dictionary1":
    bank(user_input)

elif user_input == "dictionary2":
    bank(user_input)
else:
    print("unknown command")
```

Also for your code, when you used the bank function, you put the variable 'name' in speech marks. If you want to input the variable name in the function bank, dont add speech marks. :)

Comment: That code obviously wont work with what you need to do, is use that format, and adapt to it your needs :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try doing this:

```
dict1={...}
dict2={...}

def bank(x):
     if x=="dict1":
         usedict=dict1
     elif x=="dict2":
         usedict=dict2
     else:
         print("No dictionary found with input given")
     ## write your program using usedict
x=input("enter which dictionary to use")
bank(x)
```

Remember, if you want to use the dictionary usedict outside the function as well, use global usedict inside the function